# AWS: Set up cloudfront and issued certificate. Still not secure

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have been using the WP AWS S3 Offsite-upload plugin for a while now and recently it has asked me to create a url for my site as a subdomain and use that to point to my cloudfront.

so, I changed my DNS records to add a CNAME

```
sub.mydomain.com > somestring.cloudfront.net
```

When I went to any files sub.mydomain.com/wp-content/wp-uploads/2018/10/image1.jpg I get a 'not secure' alert.

After a google I this link on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html

Using the steps there  I went to the AWS Certificate Manager and generated a certificate for:

```
images.mydomain.com
```

and then downloaded the CNAME CSV file. I then added that CNAME to my DNS Zone editer on my CPanel and waited 24 hours.

Still I am getting a 'not secure' message.

In the AWS console the certificate says **issued** but not in use.

How do I get my subdomain `images.subdomain.co.uk` to point to my cloudfront installation?

*I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult so apologies if i'm being a noob*

Comment: You do not seem to have mentioned whether the certificate shows "Issued" (in the ACM console)... or whether you went back to CloudFront and actually configured it to *use* the certificate... or whether you are typing the `https://...` in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have issued the certificate but you have not to use `let's encrypt` to use ssl properly.

---> Just open your site and inspect element

---> then go to Security tab where it says suggest you what exactly the error is

solution

To resolve you have to use let's encrypt so you get ssl issued and integrated perfect.for that please follow these steps : https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Route 53, to point your subdomain 'images.subdomain.co.uk' to CloudFront distribution, you need to create an Alias record set in your Hosted Zone. Select Alias: 'Yes' radio button while creating the record set and you should be able to see your CloudFront distribution in the drop down if it is in Deployed state.